# Android 13: bandwidth throttling doesn't work

Tags: xiaomi, miui, android-13

[Android 13 offers a network rate limit for WiFi and xG connections](https://www.digit.in/features/mobile-phones/how-to-limit-internet-and-wi-fi-hotspot-speeds-on-android-smartphones-65942.html) via the developer options. I'm using a Xiaomi smartphone with MIUI 14 sporting Android 13. However it doesn't limit the actual speed: I've tried it setting it to 128 and 256KBps and it still downloads at the max. speed my WiFi offers.

Am I probably not alone with this problem and this is a bug or not supported by Xiaomi?
Or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Most likely this is a Xiomi bug. Such rarely used features are often not covered by any test plan the manufacturer perform before releasing a new version.

Comment: @Robert In the meantime I read elsewhere that this feature requires support to be enabled in the Kernel as well. I suppose this isn't the case, at least for now.

Comment: Does it work if you're on 4G/5G data, rather than Wi-Fi?